# Angular 2 Route Translation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, translate, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I have a web app that support multiple languages. I am successfully translating the content of the app with @ngx-translate.
However; I also need to translate the route link.
My link look like this

> www.somewebsite.com/dashboard.

Now when I change the language to something like Turkish;
I need the link look like

> www.somewebsite.com/anasayfa.

How can I achieve that easily?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could define another route.

Comment: did the answer help

Comment: yeah, for sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please upvote if this helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of bad idea to implement, since you need to build several routes for each language. Generally i would recommend you to configure routes with languages. For example,

**`www.somewebsite.com/en/dashboard`**

and if its a differencet language then it should be,

**`www.somewebsite.com/es/dashboard.`**

However if you really want to build with different language routes then you have to do,

```
create a new path : { path: ':lang/dashboard', component: dashboardComponent }

this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            translate.use(params['lang']);
            switch (params['lang']) {
                case 'en':
                    location.replace(<code>index.html#/${params['lang']}/dashboard</code>)
                        break;
                case 'fr':
                    location.replace(<code>index.html#/${params['lang']}/anasayfa</code>);
                        break;
            }

  })
```

also you can have different routes if you dont like the above implementation